# How to retrieve only an ASP.NET MVC3 Collection's Count without element properties

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, collections

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 to track hits on a set of stored links.  I run into problems when displaying the hits' counts.  I think this is because since I am using lazy loading, whenever I call

```
link.Hits.Count
```

it loads all of each hit's data, including such things as agent and referrer information.  (Hits is a Collection.)  This is an issue when a link has over 9000 hits.  Is there a way of just getting the Hits' Count without it pulling in the Hits' data?

Comment: Need more information. I'm assuming you're using an ORM from the reference to lazy loading, what ORM are you using?

Comment: Can you use the Count() extension method instead of the Count property?

Comment: @Betty -- Thank you, but Count() fares no better.

Comment: @rossisdead -- I am using Entity Framework's model first design.

Answer (score 0):

If the Hits has been written like this, the Count will work:

```
Hits = repository.GetAll(....).Where(....);
```

But if like this, the Count will not work, because the ToList() has already loaded all the data:

```
Hits = repository.GetAll(....).Where(....).ToList();
```